# How to add padding to drawable backgrounds?

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I am trying to make a custom EditText background for an application and I am having some difficulty formatting it properly. I want the EditText field to be underlined and so I have this code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-3dp"
        android:right="-3dp"
        android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The issue I am having though is that it seems like the background cannot extend past the bounds of the View object, so that if I want the underline to be further below the EditText, I have to add padding to the View itself:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_default_dark"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"/>
```

I really don't like the idea of having to change dozens of EditText widgets if I want to change the background, so I was wondering if there a way to add the padding in the drawable resource?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with xml drawables--there is the `<padding>` tag available in the `Shape` tag.  Or you could create a `style` and apply it to every `EditText`. That way you have all the `EditText` the same and you only need to change the style to affect all of the instances.

Comment: @Barns, thanks so much! Didn't even think to use styles

Comment: Did you try using the  the <padding> tag  that is available within the `Shape` Tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot achieve this with shape. I have make workaround similar problem with Vector Drawable. They seems to strech correctly under buttons and can be use in place of shape drawables. You can draw such vector in svg (Adobe Illustrator). Then convert to Android Vector. And adjust in code.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="200"
    android:viewportHeight="40">

    <path
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeMiterLimit="10"
        android:pathData="M 16 40 L 184 40" />
</vector>
```